# I want VerifyTextPresent to be only true when visible in Selenium

Tags: php, html, selenium

When I use verifyTextPresent, or assert. IE and Chrome will find the text of hidden elements as well. I have a table that can be filtered by user input.

```
<table>
<td>one</td>
<td>two</td>
<td>three</td>
</table>
```

so say the user types two, the code will change to this

```
<table>
<td visibility:hidden>one</td>
<td>two</td>
<td visibility:hidden>three</td>
</table>
```

then I go to selenium and I say

```
verifyTextNotPresent("one")
```

in IE8 and Chrome, it fails. In FireFox, it succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isVisible()` to check whether an element is visible or not, so I suggest you use that on the container containing your text or switch to Selenium 2 where I think it is the default.

Comment: the table is very dynamic, the row that I'm testing for is going to have a different ID every time I run the test, so I don't know how I would send the proper locator to isVisible(). 

As far as Selenium 2, do you know off hand if there is support for PHPUnit? That's what all my tests are written in right now.